# I am trying to develop a GET API to filter out results from Database based on Radio Button selection that's without a submit button in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Front end of the api:

[image: Front end of the api]

I am trying to develop a GET API to filter out results from Database based on Radio Button selection and then populate the 'State/Province' dropdown with that filtered data. Like, if the United States will be selected then the dropdown list should be populated with states from US. I am fairly new to .NET Core and so finding it hard to figure out how to start with this. Can anyone help me with the code skeleton an API like this should follow?

I tried to look for some YouTube tutorials but most of them were on WinForms. I also looked at a few codes but had difficulty in understanding them and following the same in my API.

Comment: read about onClick, onChange event handlers, show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: First take 2 radio button. set name as `state`, `province`, then `on  radio button click` event call the API which will return a list based on the `value` selected on the `radio button`

Comment: In addtion, please share your `front end code` instead of screenshot.

Comment: Hey @MdFaridUddinKiron, I am responsible just for developing the Backend part that is the API so I dont have access to the front end code. That part is being handled by the front end team. I just want to know how to access the Radio button selection from my API and return the filtered result into a dropdown list as show in the screenshot. Thanks for the support

Comment: Hey @AnandSowmithiran, I have just built the model for it as of now and I am not able to figure out how to start with this. Can we connect somewhere if you are okay with it?

Comment: What does your `front-end` send to your `API`, how does they sent you? What response they are expecting from backend? Based on `country`, `city` `state` and `zip` what would you search on your API and what data they need? Do you have these clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me with the code skeleton an API like this should
> follow?

Based on the scenario, you should know how your frontend team sends request to your API. At the same time being an API developer you should deal with the country name as your API parameter, not how the radio button change event works -- as you said it should be front-end teams's concern. Therefore, I am providing you the complete example:

**Model Data:**

Let's assume you have following country and states:

*Country:*

```
public static List<Country> ListOfCountry = new List<Country>()
        {
            new Country() { CountryId =101, CountryName ="INDIA", },
            new Country() { CountryId =102, CountryName ="UnitedStates", },
            new Country() { CountryId =103, CountryName ="UK", },
            new Country() { CountryId =104, CountryName ="Canada", },
        };
```

*State:*

```
public static List<State> ListOfState = new List<State>()
        {
            //INDIA
            new State() { CountryId =101, StateId =1, StateName = "Delhi" },
            new State() { CountryId =101, StateId =2, StateName = "Haydrabad" },
            new State() { CountryId =101, StateId =3, StateName = "Pune" },
            //USA
            new State() { CountryId =102, StateId =4, StateName = "New York" },
            new State() { CountryId =102, StateId =5, StateName = "Silicon Valley" },
            new State() { CountryId =102, StateId =6, StateName = "Dallaus" },
            //UK
            new State() { CountryId =103, StateId =7, StateName = "London" },
            new State() { CountryId =103, StateId =8, StateName = "Cardif" },
            new State() { CountryId =103, StateId =9, StateName = "Sundarland" },
             //Candada
            new State() { CountryId =104, StateId =10, StateName = "Alberta" },
            new State() { CountryId =104, StateId =11, StateName = "Ontario" },
            new State() { CountryId =104, StateId =12, StateName = "Manitoba" },
        };
```

**Note:** Seeing the list I hope you have enough knowledge to write the POCO model class yourself.

**API Controller:**

```
public class CascadingDropdownController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetStateByCountryName(string countryName)
        {
            int getCountryId = ListOfCountry.Where(name => name.CountryName == countryName).Select(id => id.CountryId).FirstOrDefault();
            var state = ListOfState.Where(cId => cId.CountryId == getCountryId).ToList();

            return Ok(state);

        }
         public IActionResult Index() // This action is for the view
          {
              return View();
          }

}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" name="country" value="UnitedStates" /><span><strong> United States</strong></span>
        <input type="radio" name="country" value="Canada" /> <span><strong> Canada</strong></span>
        <input type="radio" name="country" value="India" /> <span><strong> India</strong></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td> <span><strong>City</strong></span> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" /></td>
            <td>
                <span><strong>State/Province</strong></span>
                <select class="form-control" id="ddlState"> </select>
            </td>
            <td><span><strong>Zip/Postal Code</strong></span><input id="zip" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip/Postal Code" /> </td>
            <td><input type="submit" style="margin-top:22px" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
           
        </tr>
     
    </table>
   
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ddlState = $('#ddlState');
            ddlState.empty();
            ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Choose State'));
            $('input[type=radio][name=country]').change(function () {
                var country = "";
                if (this.value == 'UnitedStates') {
                  country = "UnitedStates"
                }
                else if (this.value == 'Canada') {
                    country = "Canada"
                }
                else if (this.value == 'India') {
                    country = "INDIA"
                }

                if (country != "") {
                    var ddlState = $('#ddlState');
                    ddlState.empty();
                    ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Please wait ...'));


                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:5094/CascadingDropdown/GetStateByCountryName',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { countryName: country },
                        success: function (d) {

                            ddlState.empty(); // Clear the please wait
                            ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Choose State'));
                            $.each(d, function (i, states) {
                                ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val(states.stateId).html(states.stateName));
                            });
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error!');
                        }
                    });
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Here `'input[type=radio][name=country]').change` based on `radio button` change event you have to get the selected country name then need to call your API that is `GetStateByCountryName` which expecting a country name as parameter and base on that parameter search the list of state and return you are done.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** I have used a static list of country and states you all need to search from your database. In addition, I have set a submit button.n Nonetheless, it's doing nothing at this stage, hence it will required for any further submission.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Farid, this will surely help me with my assignment. At this point, my API is just responsible for populating the 'State' dropdown based on selected value in Radio button but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, Glad to assit you on this.